# Generic error message in Communities

Tags: apex, trigger, community, error-messages

In Communities, I'm getting a generic error message(An error occurred while trying to update the record.Please try again) instead of my custom error message. Can some one please help me, if there is any setting I missed for communities in Salesforce?

Explanation: -  I have a trigger on user object where I'm checking user's Email domain should contain account's domain(have a custom field on account object it will have domain value) if not I want to throw an error message. But instead of my custom message, I'm getting generic one. Please suggest a fix to it.

Note: - It's working as excepted if I login directly into salesforce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one custom generic Exception page where you will find these lines

```
<apex:outputText styleClass="title" value="{!$Label.site.error}">
     <apex:param value="{!$Site.ErrorMessage}"/>
      <!-- this parameter needs to be italic in the site.error label -->
</apex:outputText>
```

Just replace the `ErrorMessage` with `ErrorDescription` and you will get actual error message. After fix revert back to generic message.

```
<apex:outputText styleClass="title" value="{!$Label.site.error}">
     <apex:param value="{!$Site.ErrorDescription}"/>
     <!-- this parameter needs to be italic in the site.error label -->
</apex:outputText>
```